# jQuery Ui dialog always has horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, scrollbar

I am designing a form in a popup dialog (no iframe, just html) and no matter what I do there is always a scrollbar (see image below).

[image: Horizontal scrollbar]

Currently the dialog width is being set to auto (via the dialog options) but I have tried 100% and though the window stretches, the scrollbar remains.

I read through [this post about scrollbars with iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856258/iframe-in-jquery-ui-dialog-causes-horizontal-scrollbar-on-parent) and have tried playing with .ui-widget-overlay in firebug to no effect. Interestingly enough, there is no scrollbar in IE7, though the box is stretched to the whole screen and the scrollbar re-appears as soon as you try to resize.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue before I spend even more time on it?

I am running `jquery 1.4.3` with `jquery ui 1.8.6`

Comment: Could you provide CSS that you are using?

Comment: @drupality - It's a client site so I can't provide all of it and there is a ton. If you can give me a clue of which element(s) you suspect I can provide that.

Comment: If you had a jsFiddle example or post the html/js/css that you're using, that would help.  A live example would be best.

Comment: @David, ok, I'll see if I can put something together. I was hoping this was a common problem that people had ready-answers for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that you have an element inside the dialog with 100% width and margin or padding. Then the width of the element will be 100% plus the margin and padding. See if you can set width to auto on elements with these kinds of properties.